# angularjs: the preferred way to update multiple viewports

Tags: templates, angularjs

I am looking for the angularjs way to:

while updating the page body with content:

- update a shared header with alerts
- update a shared footer with stuff

i cant see an easy way to do this because you can put the ng-view attribute on a single element, but i dont want that element to be the  tag because i want have a shared header and footer that is reused between multiple pages.

---

Basically coming from jinja template inheritance, how does one translate that into angularjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can make use of `ng-include` for putting header and footer.
`ng-view` is used for the partials that change according to url path.

Comment: Then you can add a shared service that fires events that can be caught by any controller that requires the service.